# Find bounds for probability of unions and intersections

Tags: probability

At least one, but no more than three, of the events $A_r, 1 \leq r \leq n$, occur, where $n \geq 3$. The probability of at least two occurring is ½. If $\mathbb{P}(A_r) = p, \mathbb{P}(A_r \cap A_s) = q, r \neq s,$ and $ \mathbb{P}(A_r \cap A_s \cap A_t) = x, r<s<t,$ show that $p \geq 3/(2n)$, and $q \leq 4/n$.

So because at least one $A_r$ occurs, I have

$1 = \mathbb{P}(\bigcup_r A_r) = \sum_r \mathbb{P} (A_r) - \sum_{r<s} \mathbb{P} (A_r \cap A_s) + \sum_{r<s<t} \mathbb{P}(A_r \cap A_s \cap A_t) = np - {n \choose 2}q + {n \choose 3}x$

Because at least two $A_r$ occur with probability ½

$½ = \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{r<s} (A_r \cap A_s) \right) = \sum_{r<s} \mathbb{P} (A_r \cap A_s) - \sum_{r<s, t<u, (r,s)\neq (t,u)} \mathbb{P}(A_r \cap A_s \cap A_t \cap A_u) + \sum_{r<s,t<u,v<w, (r,s)\neq(t,u)\neq(v,w)} \mathbb{P} (A_r \cap A_s \cap A_t \cap A_u \cap A_v \cap A_w) + ...$

Solution (continued)
There are three lots of "triplet" intersections in the second sum and one lot of "triplet" intersections in the third sum (see Mick A's comment below). So the equation above becomes

$½ = {n \choose 2}q - 3{n \choose 3}x + {n \choose 3}x$

Sum the first equation and the one above gives

$3/2 = np - {n \choose 3}x$

It follows that $p \geq 3/(2n)$.

Sum the first equation with the one immediately above gives

\begin{align*}
\frac{5}{2} &= 2np - 2{n \choose 2}q \\
{n \choose 2}q &= 2np - \frac{5}{2}\\
\frac{n(n-1)}{2}q &\leq \frac{4n - 5}{2}\\
q &\leq \frac{4n-4 -1}{n(n-1)} = \frac{4}{n} - \frac{1}{n(n-1)} < \frac{4}{n}
\end{align*}

For the inequality of $q$ I think the original problem statement has a mistake. Logically it is impossible that $q \leq 4/n$ because $1/(n(n-1)) > 0$ $\forall n$.

Comment: This may be related to the Bonferroni inequalities, which see.

Comment: "no more than three...occur" so the last sum is empty, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson not necessarily, since if s = t, then it is an intersection of three events.

Comment: Is your $t$ equal to $x$?

Comment: Yes. That last term with r,s,t,u results in 4 lots of intersection of (r,s,t): (r,s)&(r,t) and (r,s)&(s,t) and (r,t)&(s,t) and (r,s)&(r,t)&(s,t). You then have 2 eqns in p,q,x to work with along with basic restrictions 0 <= p,q,x <= 1.

Comment: @GregMartin no, $t$ is an index, $x$ is a probability.

Comment: @MickA agree. Does (r,s)&(r,t)&(s,t) come from the "sixtet" intersections (the third sum)? If so would there be more combinations? I'm not sure how many.

Comment: Yes, the (r,s)&(r,t)&(s,t) one comes from that new term you just added. It has different sign to the term with the other 3 so you have 3 negative, 1 positive leaving -2 of them. So the equation should end up: 1/2 = (n choose 2)q - 2(n choose 3)x

Comment: @MickA Thank you! That solved it!

Comment: So if we have a solution, would someone please write it up and post it as an answer? 90593, you can post it as an answer to your own question, that's encouraged on this website.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I wrote up the solution under the problem statement.

Comment: @user90593 Good job. I wouldn't say the $q$ inequality is logically impossible. It's totally valid but you've actually proved a stronger result is all. They possibly use $q <= 4/n$ because it's a simpler term than $\dfrac{4n-5}{n\left(n-1\right)}$.

Comment: @MickA Thank you. I respectfully disagree. Assume that q<= 4/n, then it is possible that $\frac{4n-5}{n(n-1)} = 4/n$, so $4n-5 = 4(n-1)$ and $4n-5 = 4n-4$ which is a contradiction. I would be grateful if you could point out when it is possible for q = 4/n.

Comment: Hi @user90593. I'm not saying you could have $q=4/n$. In fact, you've proven you can't. All I'm saying is that given the assumptions of the questions, their statement $q \leq 4/n$ is true. Say if a question asks you to prove the probability of a certain event is $\leq 1/2$. And you in fact prove it is $\leq 0.4927$. You have done what they asked and improved on it slightly. Their statement that the probability is $\leq 1/2$ is still true though because anything $\leq 0.4927$ is also $\leq 1/2$.

Comment: @MickA I get what you said now. Thank you.